# Opening a file in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created a .wsf file which on opening executes some functionality.  I need to open this file in vb for my project to work, but i don't know how to do this. Can you please provide an example of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to load the program via file and open it on the program launch? Or a way to load the file from the program?

Answer (score 0):

Wirte Shell("PATH OF THE FILE")
that' it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [System.Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method to launch a file:

```
System.Process.Start("C:\yourfile.wsf")
```